# UK - Probation and extensions

Tags: resignation, human-resources, united-kingdom, manager, probation

Is it possible for a manger to extend a probation (almost indefinitely) without HR being involved?

I believe that my manger has been lying to me about my probationary status for quite some time, to what end, I do not know.

I started in June and handed in resignation last week.

In July it was extended by 1 month due to travel constraints - this letter is on file with HR stating that the probation ended on 1st October.
I also received a copy of this letter.

Around the first, for arguments sake we'll say it was the 2nd, I had a 121(mostly meeting to discuss targets, process and anything else really - mine were mainly me walking on eggshells trying to improve my chances of existing the probation period) with manager, he congratulated me on passing probation.  I then told him of an incident that had occurred (in another post).

Since then I've been told by him that my probation is ongoing, it started out with a 2 month extension, then it went to December and then finally the end of January.  No real reasons, just 'it is' - I've received no letters, no HR contact, just verbal via manager.

HR have no record of these extensions.

So, is this a thing?  Is it allowed, does it stand - did he over extend his rights as a manager? Is this even allowed to happen?

Apologies for the number of questions - hopeful that someone may have an answer or two.

This continued probation was a contributing factor to my eventual resignation.

many thanks!

Comment: By 121 do you mean a one on one meeting or does this refer to something else?

Comment: @Myles - Sorry, yes. It's a monthly meeting between manager and employee, usually to discuss targets and so on

Comment: What practical difference does this make, since you're resigning?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - wouldn't you like to know if it happened to you?  I have several friends that work there still, one of which has the same manager.  I don't think anyone should be made to think they're on probation and at risk of losing their job when that isn't the case - I do not want my friends to experience that same that I did.

Comment: If I wanted to know, I'd have found out long before resigning.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, this is the same instance.  I do not think that the probation extension that related to the hygiene was legitimate.  It started off as 2 months and then eventually ended at the end of Jan.  It's difficult to raise questions of HR when you're worried about attracting attention to yourself.

Comment: It's a bit  late to argue about legitimacy. It was made, you left, none of us has all the details, there's nothing in what you've said that makes it obviously _not_ legitimate... Time to accept that it happened, learn from it, and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally if a probationary period were to be extended you would need to sign off on it to acknowledge that you are aware of a modification to the conditions of your employment.  If HR has no record that there was a modification to these conditions and you did not sign off on it, then likely you are in fact finished your probation.

Unfortunately this is not 100% as local law may affect what it truly means to be on probation and what the employers responsibilities are in this respect.  Best talk to your local employment council/department of labor.

Comment: thank you Myles, your time and help is very much appreciated.  I have intentions of speaking to employment(guys) but first wanted to ask the stack community in case I was overlooking something.

Comment: @meh Can you add a country tag and update us after you talk to the employment guys?

Comment: absolutely, it'll probably be next week sometime but I'll certainly provide details.

Comment: @meh For UK please refer to this http://www.safeworkers.co.uk/employment-probation-periods-what-you-need-know.html